# Visual editor for Craft 3

Tags: craft3, editor

Client is coming from WP and is used to Elementor (https://elementor.com/). Can create own rows, columns, etc. in content. Is there a visual editor for Craft 3? Client hasn't specifically requested but think they'd like more than just rich text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for "drag and drop" I would use matrix blocks. You can define text block, image block, video block, etc that would be available in Elementor.

Maybe you don't get as much out of the box as a plugin, but you are able to define exactly what is available to the client.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I'll add a bit more thought to the answer - a rich text editor is just that. A rich text editor, not a content editor.

I realized that the Elementor plugin is more than a rich text editor, but I would be interested to see what the output is like. Meaning, is the content structured at all? Or is it just a big blob? From a publishing standpoint, that would be fine. But, if you are truly managing content, and/or the types of content - you're going to want more control. [Check out this article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-content-builder-in-craft-cms) to get you rolling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have to define the elements that the client will manage for a page.
If you watch the [video in craftcms.com landing page](https://craftcmsassets.craftcdn.com/images/homepage/live-features-video1.mp4) you can see how that would look like.

The elements on the left are the fields that you would define (from a field type) and then you would add them to a Craft section.

For the **rich text** you have [Redactor](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor) field type, which you can add to your Craft instance when installing the **Redactor** plugin in the plugin store.